# Using Criteria, how do I get a list of result base on the max(column) in Grails GORM

Tags: grails, hql, grails-orm, criteria

Let's say I have this GORM objects

```
Class Person {
  String country
  int age
  String Name
}
```

I would like to get the oldest person for each country

I can get the projection this way, but I would like to have the list of Person objects.

```
def results = Person.withCriteria {
  projections {
    groupProperty("country")
    max('age')
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def countries = Person.executeQuery(
    "select distinct person.country from Person person")
def persons = countries.collect{ country ->
    Person.executeQuery(
        "from Person as person1 " +
        "where person1.country='${country}' and person1.age=" +
            "("+
            "select max(age) "+
            "from Person as person2 "+
            "where person2.country='${country}' "+
            "group by person2.country "+
            ")"
         )
}
```

Hopefully this helps. This will return a list of lists as there is the possibility that for each country there is a list of people that have the maximum age.